# Is there any functionality in Apache Ignite where we can pass expression from client to be executed inside cluster

Tags: ignite

Is there any functionality in Apache Ignite where we can pass expression from client to be executed inside cluster which can be changed based on need. For example:

cache.invoke("Expression 1");

cache.invoke("Expression 2");

cache.invoke("Expression 3");

Answer (score 1):

You have two options depending on your needs:

- [Ignite compute APIs](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/distributed-computing/distributed-computing)
- [Ignite entry processor](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/CacheEntryProcessor.html)